# Calculate the line integrals of these conservative functions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, line-integrals, greens-theorem

1. $F := (\frac{x}{x^2+y^2+1} ,\frac{y}{x^2+y^2+1})$ 
   and $Γ := (x, y) : x^2 + y^2 − 2x = 1$
   , $Γ$ traversed counterclockwise
2. $F := (2xy^2z, 2x^2yz, x^2y^2 - 2z)$ and $Γ :=$ {$(cos(t),\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} sin (t),\frac{1}{2} sin (t)$}, $0 ≤ t ≤ 2π$

The question is to compute $\int_ΓF$

In both cases I got that $\int_ΓF = 0$ where in 1. I used Green's theorem, that is $\int_ΓF = \int_Γ F_{2x} - F_{1y}$, where $F_{2x} = F_{1x}$ are the partial derivatives of $F$ which is conservative.

And in 2. I just applied the line integral formula $\int_ΓF = \int_a^b F(r(t))\frac{dr}{dt} dt$

Is it okay that I got 0 as an answer?

Comment: Okay. Please show us your work.

Comment: There’s a relevant theorem about integrals of conservative vector fields over closed loops that I suspect you’ve been taught.

Comment: @amd yes I know it. If $F$ is a conservative vector field, then its line integral over closed loops $=0$. So it's fine that I got $0$ as an answer right?

Comment: If you got any other result, then you did something wrong. As well, you could write down the value of both integrals directly after verifying that both vector fields were closed.